# Unable to run .sh file via ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I have ubuntu server setup, where I want to execute shell scripts. I have tried the following code but with no luck.

ansible.yml file:

```
- hosts: testserver
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: copy files and execute it
    script: /media/anish/linux_files/ansible-terraform/play.sh
```

play.sh file:

```
#!bin/sh
echo 'hello'
```

It gives following error:

```
fatal: [13.213.12.27]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "stderr": "Shared connection to 13.213.12.27 closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to 13.213.12.27 closed."], "stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617116935.2170017-256995291519228/play.sh: not found\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617116935.2170017-256995291519228/play.sh: not found"]}
```

However, I can execute it by other way: copying file to the server via copy command and executing it there. But what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Probably not the root cause of your issue, but header in `play.sh` should be: `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I can execute it by other way: copying file to the server via copy command and executing it there. But what's wrong with this approach?

If you want to run it on the destination host, you need to copy the script first.

If you rather run it locally on the host on which you run Ansible, you need to add

```
delegate_to: localhost
```

```
- hosts: testserver
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: copy files and execute it
    script: /media/anish/linux_files/ansible-terraform/play.sh
    delegate_to: localhost
```